# DL4J: set "channels_first" config

Tags: java, keras, dl4j

I'm trying to load a pretrained **Keras** model into Java app using **DL4J**. 
When training in Keras I used "channels_first" image_data_format, and now, in DL4J I can not load my model properly, because it tries to use "**channels_last**" configuration.

Is there in DL4J any similar function as **set_image_data_format("channels_first)** in Keras?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set such a property, because you simply don't need to. The way Keras model import for DL4J is designed is that you provide your `json` or `h5` file and DL4J will figure out which Keras version you're using, which backend and in particular which data format.

See here for an introduction to the API:
https://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras

Here's a list of supported features: 
https://deeplearning4j.org/keras-supported-features

To get you started you might want to look at a few tests, like these [model configuration](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-modelimport/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/nn/modelimport/keras/configurations/Keras2ModelConfigurationTest.java) or [end to end tests](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-modelimport/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/nn/modelimport/keras/e2e/KerasModelEndToEndTest.java).

If you have any questions, feel free to ping me on gitter. Also, feel free to create an [issue](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Akeras+) if you have one.